# Running docker compose states port already in use, but port scan on Network Utility shows nothing running on port

Tags: docker

I'm attempting to follow this tutorial: https://pawelgrzybek.com/configure-a-local-wordpress-development-using-docker/

After setting everything up, trying to run the container I get a failure for `wp_wordpress_1` where I get the following error:

`ERROR: for wordpress  Cannot start service wordpress: Ports are not available: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:80: bind: address already in use`

I've killed all Docker containers, and have gone into the Mac Network Utility to run a port scan for `0.0.0.0:80` but it seems like there is no utility using this port, but yet I still cannot run the docker build.

Comment: Does mac include ss? Looking for `ss -lnt` output.

Comment: I see that the wordpress container has the `restart: always` policy. Make sure the docker daemon isn't spinning it back up right after you're killing it. I would get rid of all the `restart: always` policies from all the containers and restart the docker daemon and then run `docker-compose up`